# How can I capture WPF events from a Winforms app

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.5

I have an WPF User control which is is hosted in an Elementhost. I use elementhost to include an WPF user control in my classical Windows forms app.

Now, from Windows forms side I am trying to capture the mouseDown event that is produced in an WPF label but I don't know how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pass a delegate or object with a method into the wpf. Handle the wpf events in wpf and call whatever you passed in. Winforms and wpf are oil and water they don't mix so well without effort.

Comment: @Andy how to call the delegat from wpf? using invoke?¨Could you post a code snippet? or tell me some example in the web? What I first did is to register a routed event with RegisterRoutedEvent(...) in WPF side and then from WPF raise this event using RaiseEvent(...) and from winform side I suscribe to this WPF event. I don't know if this is the best approach.

Comment: Does it work? A routedevent propogated up through the ui tree. The wpf ui. I wouldn't think it'll reliably cross over into winforms.

Comment: @Andy Yes, it's working perfectly. I can confirm and assure you it 100%. I am using it in this way and it works but I am asking it to see if there is a better approach that mine. I wanted to contrast opinions with other people.

Comment: Hi,@Rodri . Is there an update on the question? You could check my answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

A case might be able to help you. The winform form calls the wpf control.

1. Create a WPF custom control. The xaml code of the control is as follows.

   ```
   <Grid>        
         <Image  Margin="10,10,10,90" x:Name="img" Stretch="Uniform" Opacity="1">
        <Image.BitmapEffect>
            <DropShadowBitmapEffect Opacity="1" />
        </Image.BitmapEffect>
    </Image>
    <TextBox Background="Transparent"  Foreground="White" Height="40" FontSize="32" Margin="44,0,56,36" x:Name="txtBox1" Opacity="0.5" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" /> </Grid>
   ```
2. You need to add the corresponding function to set the effect. The code is as follows.

   ```
    public void SetSource(string fileName)
    {
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName) );
    }

    public void SetOpacity(double opacity)
    {
        img.Opacity = opacity;
    }
    //
    public string GetText()
    {
        return txtBox1.Text;
    }
   ```
3. Create a Winform application and add a reference, otherwise the control will not work properly. The list of references is pictured below.

   [image]
4. Regenerate the solution. On the left toolbar, a WPF control appears and drag it to the form.

   [image]
5. Use the button control in the winform project to call the corresponding function.

   ```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((UserControl1)elementHost1.Child).SetSource(@"C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\Saved Pictures\9837f99502eba3d01d4fb671cab20c15.jpg");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ((UserControl1)elementHost1.Child).SetOpacity(0.5);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string text = ((UserControl1)elementHost1.Child).GetText();

        label1.Text = text;
    }
   ```
6. Test items: The left side is the traditional Winform control. The right side is the imported WPF control. You can clearly see the "translucent" effect of the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve. Below is a simple example.You can edit the MouseDown event of the UserControl as needed.
If there is a problem, please make your problem clearer and show me the complete code sample that can reproduce your problem for analysis.

UserControl:

```
 <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" MouseDown="label_MouseDown" Background="AliceBlue" Width="300" Height="200" />

    </Grid>


    private void label_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");

    }
```

Add the UserControl reference in the WinForms project, drag and drop the UserControl on the Form1 designer after rebuilding the WinForms project.

The result of running the project and clicking the Label in the UserControl is shown in the figure.

[image]